# Object animation - position fails to update

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm trying to make a pong game in JavaScript. I've tried lots of stuff, but whatever I do won't get the ball to move.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Game = {};

var Player = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Player.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 80);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

var Ball = function(x, y, diam) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.diam = diam;
  this.xvel = 5;
  this.yvel = 5;
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(canvas.width/2 - 10, canvas.height/2 - 10, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

Ball.prototype.moveBall = function() {
  this.x = this.x + this.xvel;
  this.y = this.y + this.yvel;
};


var p1 = new Player(20, canvas.height/2 - 40);
var p2 = new Player(canvas.width-20-20, canvas.height/2 - 40);
var ball = new Ball(canvas.width/2 - 10, canvas.height/2 - 10, 20);

Game.draw = function() { p1.draw(); p2.draw(); ball.draw(); };
Game.update = function() { ball.moveBall(); };
Game.run = function() { Game.update(); Game.draw(); };
Game.fps = 50;

Game._intervalId = setInterval(Game.run, 1000 / Game.fps);
```

I can't get the ball to move. Any Ideas? Also, what the neater way of classes? Is there a different way to do it than with functions?

Maybe like

```
class Apple {
    function draw() {
        //draw here
    }
}
```

Comment: No javascript errors?

Comment: No javascript errors :/

Answer (score 4):

You are always drawing the ball in the same place, dead-center:

```
ctx.rect(canvas.width/2 - 10, canvas.height/2 - 10, 20, 20);
```

You're updating `this.x` and `this.y` elsewhere, but not *using* them. Try:

```
ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
```

Now you have the problem of knowing when to *stop* moving, but that's a separate question.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Game = {};

var Player = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Player.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 80);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

var Ball = function(x, y, diam) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.diam = diam;
  this.xvel = 5;
  this.yvel = 5;
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

Ball.prototype.moveBall = function() {
  this.x = this.x + this.xvel;
  this.y = this.y + this.yvel;
};


var p1 = new Player(20, canvas.height/2 - 40);
var p2 = new Player(canvas.width-20-20, canvas.height/2 - 40);
var ball = new Ball(canvas.width/2 - 10, canvas.height/2 - 10, 20);

Game.draw = function() { p1.draw(); p2.draw(); ball.draw(); };
Game.update = function() { ball.moveBall(); };
Game.run = function() { Game.update(); Game.draw(); };
Game.fps = 50;

Game._intervalId = setInterval(Game.run, 1000 / Game.fps);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="300px" width="300px" />
```

Comment: Took me 30 seconds more to reach the same conclusion. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I got your ball moving.  you had just forgot to set the position to this.x and this.y in the draw function.

you'll notice it leaves a streak.  So you'll need to either (1) clear everything and redraw everything on each frame, or (2), keep an oldx and oldy and draw white over oldx oldy before drawing black at x and y.  Happy coding.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var Game = {};

      var Player = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      }

      Player.prototype.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 80);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }

      var Ball = function(x, y, diam) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.diam = diam;
        this.xvel = 5;
        this.yvel = 5;
      }

      Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      };

      Ball.prototype.moveBall = function() {
        this.x = this.x + this.xvel;
        this.y = this.y + this.yvel;
      };


      var p1 = new Player(20, canvas.height/2 - 40);
      var p2 = new Player(canvas.width-20-20, canvas.height/2 - 40);
      var ball = new Ball(canvas.width/2 - 10, canvas.height/2 - 10, 20);

      Game.draw = function() { p1.draw(); p2.draw(); ball.draw(); };
      Game.update = function() { ball.moveBall(); };
      Game.run = function() {console.log("hi"); Game.update(); Game.draw(); };
      Game.fps = 5;

      Game._intervalId = setInterval(Game.run, 1000 / Game.fps);
```

```css
#myCanvas{width:200px;height:200px}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Here's a good html canvas game instructions that follows the style you're doing pretty well:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/